# Firebase Admob Incompatible version with Firebase packages

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, admob, firebase-admob

These are the packages and there versions

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0
firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
meta: ^1.2.4
```

Gradle Properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

- Compiled SDK version: 29
- Minimum SDK version: 23
- Target SDK version:
  29

The result when building the app

```
BUILD FAILED in 5m 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       334.2s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error and I fixed it by [updating my Graddle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin), try this one:

**android/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
}
```

then update the `distributionUrl` in **gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Comment: this fixed my issue too but why we  should downgraded the version in order to work ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was:

**1- android/build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
}
```

**2- gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

**3- Run Command:**

```
flutter channel master
```

**4- Run Command:**

```
flutter clean
```